# Oracle: Return multiple values in a function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, view

I'm trying to return a multiple values in a %rowtype from a function using two table(employees and departments), but it not working for me.

```
create or replace function get_employee
 (loc in number)
return mv_emp%rowtype
as  
   emp_record mv_emp%rowtype;
begin
   select a.first_name, a.last_name, b.department_name into emp_record 
   from employees a, departments b 
   where a.department_id=b.department_id and location_id=loc;

   return(emp_record);  
end;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The above function compiled without any error? What is the type of `MV_EMP`? Ideally, it should be something like below.

```
create or replace type emp_type
(
first_name varchar2(20)
, last_name varchar2(20)
, depart_name varchar2(20)
)
/
create or replace function get_employee
 (loc in number)
return emp_type
as  
   emp_record emp_type;
begin
   select a.first_name, a.last_name, b.department_name into emp_record 
   from employees a, departments b 
   where a.department_id=b.department_id and location_id=loc;

   return(emp_record);  
end;
```

Comment: In my oracle version, 11g, the type declaration does not compile when specified like this. I had to declare the type AS OBJECT

Comment: I also had to write this syntax (in 11g): `SELECT x.some_field, y.something_else INTO myobject.field1, myobject.field2 FROM ...`

Comment: I had to initialise the object first also, like this: `myobject mytype := mytype('', '');`

Comment: Thanks @andersand. I did this in 10g and was successful.

Answer (score 1):

```
create type t_row as object (a varchar2(10));

create type t_row_tab as table of t_row;
```

We will now create a function which will split the input string.

```
create or replace function get_number(pv_no_list in varchar2) return t_row_tab is
lv_no_list t_row_tab := t_row_tab();
begin

  for i in (SELECT distinct REGEXP_SUBSTR(pv_no_list, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) no_list FROM dual
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(pv_no_list, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
  loop
  lv_no_list.extend;
  lv_no_list(lv_no_list.last) := t_row(i.no_list);
  end loop;

  return lv_no_list;

end get_number;
```

Once the function is in place we can use the table clause of sql statement to get the desired result. As desired we got multiple values returned from the function.

```
SQL> select * from table(get_number('1,2,3,4'));


A
----------
1
3
2
4
```

So now our function is simply behaving like a table. There can be a situation where you want these comma separated values to be a part of "IN" clause.

For example :

```
select * from dummy_table where dummy_column in ('1,2,3,4');
```

But the above query will not work as '1,2,3,4' is a string and not individual numbers. To solve this problem you can simply use following query.

```
select * from dummy_table where dummy_column in ( select * from table(get_number('1,2,3,4')) );
```

References : http://www.oraclebin.com/2012/12/returning-multiple-values-from-function.html

Answer (score -1):

```sql
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION Funmultiple(deptno_in IN NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER AS v_refcursur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    OPEN v_refcursor FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   emp
    WHERE  deptno = deptno_in;
    
    retun v_refcursor;
  END;
```

To call it, use:

```
variable x number
exec :x := FunMultiple(10);
print x
```

Comment: This does not even compile, even after correcting the spelling mistakes