# How to return multiple value in Oracle Database 12c

Tags: oracle, function, oracle12c

I know this question was asked in

[Oracle: Return multiple values in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841430/oracle-return-multiple-values-in-a-function)

or

[Returning multiple values from an Oracle 12c function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811959/returning-multiple-values-from-an-oracle-12c-function)

I followed them but it is causing error, I can not compile it. I am missing something, so I need help please.

my code is

```
create or replace type child_type AS OBJECT
(
  child_id_number varchar2(2000),
  child_name varchar2(2000),
  other_id varchar2(2000)
);


        CREATE or replace function children_b
        (
                   i_id_number IN VARCHAR2
        )
        RETURN child_type
        AS

child_record child_type;



    BEGIN

                  SELECT LISTAGG(ch.child_id_number, ', ')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ch.child_id_number),
                         LISTAGG(e.mail_name, ', ')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e.mail_name),
                         LISTAGG(ib.other_id,', ')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ib.other_id)

    INTO child_type.child_id_number,child_type.child_name,child_type.other_id

                         FROM entity e
                         JOIN children ch ON ch.child_id_number = e.id_number
                         JOIN ids_base ib ON ib.id_number = ch.child_id_number
                         WHERE ib.ids_type_code = 'BAN'
                         AND ch.id_number IN (i_id_number)
                         GROUP BY ch.id_number;


        return(child_record);



        End children_b;
```

The error message is Compilation errors for FUNCTION TU_ADIS.TU_CHILDREN_B

Error: PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
Line: 23
Text: INTO child_type.child_id_number,child_type.child_name,child_type.other_id

Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
Line: 24
Text: FROM bio_entity e

Error: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line: 20
Text: SELECT LISTAGG(ch.child_id_number, ', ')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ch.child_id_number),

THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: Your INTO clause references the variable by its type rather than by its name,`child_record`.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!! it is working right now!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your INTO clause change the

```
child_type.child_id_number,child_type.child_name,child_type.other_id
```

to

```
child_record.child_id_number,child_record.child_name,child_record.other_id
```

You are retrieving into an instance of the object not the object itself.
I've just created your function and that works for me.

Comment: thanks you so muuch!!!!! now I having this error  
ORA-06530 Reference to Uninitialized when I run the function. you knwo what it is?

Comment: Not sure how you are running it but the object instance returned by the function will need to be returned into something and that something will need initializing.